# How to change the cultural info to English in vc++ 6.0?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a converter code which will convert one form of data to another format. But this exe is now running in French OS. While reading the file, decimal separator and other thing will vary according to French OS.

For example, in French, the decimal separator is "," instead of ".". so how to change the cultural info to English while reading data in vc++ 6.0 and not in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I needed to do this but I think it's just to set the locale using [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

So something like:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, "English" );
```